# Python web scraper printing 'None', how can I fix it?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to do a project for school where I take a given stock ticker name and find the number of people "watching" it on SeekingAlpha, but I keep getting a 'None' value when I try to print. How can I fix this?

This is my first attempt with web scraping, but I have done some research on BeautifulSoup and figured that was the best thing to use. I am also using Anaconda environments. In my code, I am trying to find the full company name of the ticker, as well as the number of people following it on SeekingAlpha. For some reason, I am able to retrieve the company name of the ticker, but when I try to print the number of followers it says 'None'. I have tried every variation I can think of to find the followers but they have all resulted in 'None'.

[Here is the HTML: (Here I want the value 83,530)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tV9fN.png)

Here is my code:

```js
import requests
import urllib.request as urllib2
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

listOfTickers = ["ATVI", "GOOG", "AAPL", "AMZN", "BRK.B", "BRK.A", "NFLX", "SNAP"]

for i in range(len(listOfTickers)):
    ticker = listOfTickers[i]
    quotePage = Request("https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/" + ticker, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    page = urlopen(quotePage).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    company_name = soup.find("div", {"class" :"ticker-title"})
    followers_number = soup.find('div', {"class":"followers-number"})

    company= company_name.text.strip()
    #followers = followers_number.text.strip()

    print(followers_number)
    print(company)
```

Here is my Result

[image: Here is my Result:]

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following to get the required output. The content you wish to grab generates dynamically, so requests module or urllib won't be of any help. You either go for any browser simulator or [requests-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/) to do the trick. It's not necessary to make use of BeautifulSoup either. However, I kept it as it is only because you used it in the first place.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

tickers = ["ATVI", "GOOG", "AAPL", "AMZN"]

with HTMLSession() as session:
    for i in range(len(tickers)):
        quotePage = session.get("https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/{}".format(tickers[i]))
        quotePage.html.render(5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(quotePage.html.html, "lxml")
        followers_number = soup.find(class_="followers-number")
        print(followers_number)
```

Output you may get like:

```
<div class="followers-number">(<span>83,532</span> followers)</div>
<div class="followers-number" title="1,032,510">(<span>1.03M</span> followers)</div>
<div class="followers-number" title="2,065,199">(<span>2.07M</span> followers)</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same endpoint the page does to retrieve subscription info including # followers:

```
import requests

tickers = [ "atvi", "goog", "aapl", "amzn", "brk.b", "brk.a", "nflx", "snap"]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for ticker in tickers:
        r = s.get('https://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/get_subscribe_data/{}?id={}'.format(ticker, ticker)).json()
        print(ticker, r['portfolio_count'])
```

---

[image]

Comment: I tried using this but for some reason I get this error:                 
 
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Answer (score 0):

As followers count being loaded via ajax, `BeautifulSoup` can not access its value. Using headless browser like selineum/Phantojs you can get full html include javascript generateded contents. Another way would be by making extra request to endpoints where javascript make to render certain section of page. Here is a working solution

```
import requests
import urllib.request as urllib2
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree

listOfTickers = ["ATVI", "GOOG", "AAPL", "AMZN", "BRK.B", "BRK.A", "NFLX", "SNAP"]

def getFollowersCount(ticker):

    # build url 
    url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/get_subscribe_data/{}?id={}'.format(ticker.lower(), ticker.lower())

    # Using requests module not urllib.request.
    counter = requests.get(url)

    # If requests return is json than return portfolio_count otherwise 0
    try:
        return counter.json()['portfolio_count']
    except:
        return 0

for ticker in listOfTickers:

    quotePage = Request("https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/" + ticker, headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    page = urlopen(quotePage).read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

    company_name = soup.find("div", {"class" :"ticker-title"})
    #followers_number = soup.find('div', {"class":"followers-number"})
    followers_number = getFollowersCount(ticker)

    company= company_name.text.strip()
    #followers = followers_number.text.strip()

    print(followers_number)
    print(company)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to monitor Network. Shift+Ctrl+I(on windows) and see how the page send and receive data. :) You will see that data comes from 'https://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/get_subscribe_data', so this will do the job for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from requests import Session

tickers = ['atvi', 'goog','aapl', 'amzn']
storage = defaultdict(str) # storing data

URL = 'https://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/get_subscribe_data'

# Start a session. Here you can add headers, or(and) cookies
curl = Session()

for tick in tickers:
    param = {'id':tick}
    response = curl.get(f'{URL}/{tick}', params=param).json()
    storage[tick] = response['portfolio_count']

# show the results
print(storage)
```